# Ratio between electric and magnetic forces

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

Suppose I have two beams of electrons moving at speed $v$ separated by a distance $d$.  I can work out magnetic and electric forces between them...

For the magnetic force, we treat the two beams wires with current $I=nqv$ ($n$ is the number of electrons per unit length and $q$ is the charge on each electron).  The $B$ field at a distance $d$ away from one of the wires is
$$B=\frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi d}=\frac{\mu_0 nqv}{2\pi d}$$
The magnetic force per unit length between the two current carrying wires is then
$$F_\text{B}=BI=\frac{\mu_0n^2q^2v^2}{2\pi d}$$
This force is attractive if the electrons are moving in the same direction.

Now consider the electric field around the electron beams.  For one line charge of charge per unit length $\lambda=nq$, the electric field a distance $d$ away is
$$E=\frac{\lambda}{2\pi d}=\frac{nq}{2\pi\epsilon_0d}$$
and so the force per unit length on another line charge at this distance is
$$F_\text{E}=\lambda E=\frac{n^2q^2}{2\pi\epsilon_0d}$$
This force is repulsive if the beams have the same charge.

Now take the ratio of the magnitudes:
$$\frac{|F_\text{B}|}{|F_\text{E}|}=\mu_0\epsilon_0v^2=\frac{v^2}{c^2}$$

Here's my question.  For non-relativistic electrons, $v\ll c$, so this implies that the magnetic attraction between the wires is much smaller than the electric repulsion between them.  How can this be?  We always talk about current carrying wires in terms of their magnetic interaction all the time, but rarely do we consider their electrostatic interaction.  What is going on here?  Is this case different because these electron beams aren't "wires" in the sense that there is no stationary positive charge present, for example?  Is there some transformation I'm forgetting to do when I move into the reference frame of the electrons to work out the electric line charge contributions? (I don't want to use any relativity here).

Comment: Thinking about it more, I think the resolution is simply the lack of positive charge present in the wires.  It just seems odd to me that this result happens...

Comment: You correctly solved your problem. It is not weird. It is so necessary, that every instructor has correctly covered the need for the positive ions to keep the wires together.

Comment: It is not the *lack* of positive charges because there are just as much positive charge in a conductor as negative, it is neutral after all. The difference is that in a conductor the current is carried by the negative charges while they move through the the stationary positive charges. The *movement* of a charge is the source of magnetism, and there are a lot of moving charges that make up a macroscopic current.

Comment: Even though you "don't want to use relativity here", what you are doing is to derive the effect of the Lorentz transformation for the ratio between the electric and the magnetic field components as far as I can tell. How do you know that "relativity is involved"? Beta, the ratio between v and c shows up! You can apply a similar rule for quantum mechanics... if Planck's constant appears somewhere, then a quantum effect is involved. Classical physics depends nowhere on either c or h. This is, IMHO, a beautiful example of how non-classical physics creeps in, whether we want it or not.

Answer (score 0):

There will always be a repulsive force between the electron beams in all frames of reference. However, neither the magnitude of the force or the electric and magnetic fields will be the same in all frames.

Trivially we could move to the rest frame of the electrons, where there will be a repulsive force between the two lines of static electrons, but no magnetic field. For all other frames of reference that are moving parallel to the beams, the repulsive force will be reduced by the appropriate Lorentz factor and will tend towards zero as $v \rightarrow c$.

The dominance of an attractive magnetic field for the case of two current-carrying wires is because wires are electrically neutral.